# My page content doesn't show up

Tags: plugins, content

my wordpress content stopped showing it today (nothing was altered). It just stopped showing, after much troubleshooting it only shows some content that was written in raw html (note: I am using JS composer plugin; a page builder). The site needs to be delivered tomorrow, anyone to help me please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go through the [usual steps](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/) to find the problem

I think the most important are:

1. Disable Plugins

Can you log into wp-admin or is that a white screen too? If you can log in go and deactivate all your plugins and refresh the home page - can you see your content?

If so you've got a plugin clash - reactivate your plugins one at a time and see when the content stops working.

If you can't log into wp-admin, use FTP to change the name of the plugins folder - change it to "no_plugins". Now refresh the site? Does your content show (albeit messily)?

2. Try a default theme

Change the site theme to one of the default Wordpress themes, e.g. twentyseventeen. Does it work now? If it does then there's a problem within your theme and we'll need to do more diagnosing.

3. wp-config.php debugging

Open your wp-config.php file and look for

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

replace it with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);
```

And reload your site - do you get an error message?

Sorry that this post only helps you to diagnose and not fix your site, but one step at a time.